# Mediawiki Image Authentication: The image "URL.*" cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, image, apache, mediawiki

I am looking for assistance regarding the following issue that's been bugging me quite badly today. I am currently building a wiki, which is currently using the following specifications:

OS: Windows XP x86
MediaWiki 1.19.1
Apache 2.4.2
PHP 5.4.4
MySQL 5.5.25a
phpMyAdmin 3.5.2
PHP Cache 3.1.14.TS.VS9.X86.XP

I had configured image authentification for the wiki a while ago, which had to far been working well.

This was done as per the usual procedure:

- I modified $wgUploadPath with value "= "/wiki/img_auth.php";"
- I added a "Deny from all" in the .htaccess of the "/wiki/images" folder.

This had the wanted effect of modifying the URL of images and denying access to the /images folder itself. The URL is now `"http://x.x.x.x/wiki/img_auth.php/f/f0/2012-12-07_071358.png"` instead of `"http://x.x.x.x/bawiki/images/f/f0/2012-12-07_071358.png"`.

However, the situations changed earlier this week, and I do not know why or how. The images have disappeared from the wiki. Navigating to the page `http://x.x.x.x./wiki/index.php/File:2012-12-07_071358.png` and then to the image itself brings up two issues:

- In Firefox, although the URL properly appears as `"http://x.x.x.x/wiki/index.php/File:2012-12-07_071358.png"`, the following message is shown: **The image `"http://x.x.x.x/wiki/img_aug.php/f/f0/2012-12-07_071358.png"` cannot be displayed because it contains errors**
- In IE, the image is simply displayed as the "red X".

This happens with:

- .jpg files, .png files, .tif/tiff files, .bmp files (at least).

Other file types such as .PDF, .AVI, .7Z, etc. are all served properly by the wiki.

All of the images are still properly available on the server; I am able to open any of them on the server directly (so I know they do not actually contain errors). I am also able to view any other images on the wiki that are not using image authentication (for example, the logo).

I installed Firebug and had a look at the results when loading the image itself:

The request headers are:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  wikiUserName=username; wikiUserID=1; wiki_session=f67501dd979ec4f4939251b1bf9a9a5c
Host    x.x.x.x
If-Modified-Since   Fri, 02 Nov 2012 16:54:29 GMT
Referer http://x.x.x.x/wiki/index.php/File:2012-12-07_071358.png
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control   private
Connection  close
Date    Tue, 14 Jan 2014 20:00:18 GMT
Server  Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
Vary    Cookie
```

The final status of the image request is "304 Not modified", and hovering the cursor over any field states: "Failed to load the given URL".

If I remove the image authentication by commenting $wgUploadPath and "Deny from all" from .htaccess, I am able to view the images correctly again. However, this is not a configuration that is acceptable to me.

I tried to look for previous occurrences of such a problem, but couldn't find anything specifically. Would anyone be able to suggest solution? If there is any other detail that you wish for me to provide, I will do my best to answer questions.

Manual of Image Auth: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Image_Authorization
img_auth.php script: http://pastebin.com/TDaZex9Y

Comment: Are you missing a .htaccess file somewhere? Your browser-side urls don't correspond at all to what the server's reporting for errors, which means there's a rewrite occurring (or rather, ISN'T occuring).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the correct error message (I edited the OP now). The error message refers to the URL with "img_auth.php" in it. I also added a pastebin of the script. From what I can see, I don't seem to be missing a .htaccess. Those that could be involved would be the .htaccess of htdocs/wiki, which is essentially an Allow from all, and that of the htdocs/wiki/images, which is a deny from all. However, the whole point of this process is that /images is set to deny from all, and that the only way to access its content is through img_auth.php

Comment: Do you have anything enabled that would cause img_auth.php to dump out an error message?  Any message such as a PHP warning would break what should've been a binary data output.  You might try navigating directly to the image URL and see if you can notice anything.

Comment: Well, with image authentication activated in its production configuration, I cannot see the image directly. The image would be located at "http://x.x.x.x/wiki/images/5/56/2012-12-07_063326.png" (example file), but this access is denied by the .htaccess in /images. Now, I can remove the "deny from all" in there, which allows access to the folder. Then, while the img_auth.php URL doesn't work, I am actually able to see the image, which means that the server is able to serve the image.

Comment: (followup). I'm thinking that the issue might be in img_auth.php itself, but what I cannot understand is that if img_auth.php was in error, it should display another error message. I'm far from an expert in php, but its code obviously include error checking. If it did return an error, it should appear as two parameters returned by function wfforbidden.

Comment: After you've logged into the wiki, I thought you could directly navigate your browser to `http://x.x.x.x/wiki/img_auth.php/f/f0/2012-12-07_071358.png`.  That's not true?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. This is where I get the error message. The error message doesn't appear otherwise (say, when viewing a page on the wiki that has an image). In that case, the image simply doesn't show up. See http://imgur.com/8fm26Do,6RBmhSC for an example. The first image is the error message as it appears when attempting to view the image directly with img_auth.php. The second image is as it appears on a wiki page.

Comment: Fire up the Net tab of Firebug, go to that URL with the error message, then press Ctrl+F5 to force a reload.  What do you get for `Response Headers` as well as on the `Response` tab itself?

Comment: Here's what the headers look like. The response tab doesn't contain anything at all. http://i.imgur.com/oijUmXl.png

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  The browser is receiving 14.5 KB of data but thinks it isn't a valid image. If there was a way to capture that data stream perhaps it could be analyzed.

Comment: Apache 2.4.2 should not accept `Deny from all` directive, it is now `Require all denied`

Comment: Can you right-click on the broken image and select "save image as"? Or copy the image URL and download it with a download manager or something like `wget`?

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP log. It looks like the images are getting delivered, but in a garbled state. Can't tell if it's tru without actually looking at the files, but if a PHP warning started to appear and `display_errors` is on, you might have the error message prepended to .php script output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the binary image is preceded by a new line, resulting in a garbled image file. Some php code is sending this wrong new line.

Comment: More precisely and it is my current case if I do: $ curl http://x.x.x.x/wiki/img_auth.php/f/f0/2012-12-07_071358.png >foobad.png and $ curl http://x.x.x.x/bawiki/images/f/f0/2012-12-07_071358.png >foogood.png, you can remark that even if both file have the same size, they differ. The bad file is shifted with a newline at the top, losing its last character. For png it is a problem, but for a pdf it doesn't matter. I am still not able to find the bug.